# How to Interpret this lagged model?

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, data-preprocessing

[image: Lagged12Month_linearmodel]

Just a Quick Overview there are 2 lagged variables, Unemploy.L1 - lagged for 1 month, Unemploy.L12 lagged for 12 months.

Overview of variables - umemployment (unemploy, in thousands) (date, month of data collection), personal consumption expenditures (pce in billions of dollars), median duration of unemployment (uempmed in weeks) and personal savings rate (psavert)

Can Anyone help me in Interpreting unemploy.L1(1 month Lag), Unemploy.L12(12 month lag) Variables wrt coefficients ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
If you are just looking for an interpretation of the output of such regression, it seems that the coefficients for both unemploy.L1 and unemploy.L12 are significant. This is given by the p-values for such coefficients: being "small" (less than 0.001) we can reject the null hypotheses of the coefficients being not significant.

As far as the sign and the magnitude of such coefficients is concerned, short-term unemployment seems to have a positive impact, *ceteris paribus*, on the response variable. An additional "unit" of unemployment (whatever that means in your case) increases the outcome by 1.06 on average. Instead, long-term unemployment has a small negative effect, but still significant.